# Building MySQL InnoDB clustered indexes

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb

Assuming that you have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `search_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `provider_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `status` text NOT NULL,
    `imported_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `moderation` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`search_id`,`provider_id`),
    KEY `k_search_imported` (`search_id`,`imported_at`),
    KEY `k_scm` (`search_id`,`created_at`,`moderation`),
    KEY `k_sc` (`search_id`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

What I'm unsure about is why

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1;
```

Takes 19 minutes (I've populated the table with 1.2 million rows).

```
MariaDB [test] 10:53:58> show indexes from t1;
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| t1    |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | search_id   | A         |       13478 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          0 | PRIMARY           |            2 | provider_id | A         |      646982 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_search_imported |            1 | search_id   | A         |          30 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_search_imported |            2 | imported_at | A         |       46213 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_scm             |            1 | search_id   | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_scm             |            2 | created_at  | A         |      646982 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_scm             |            3 | moderation  | A         |      646982 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_sc              |            1 | search_id   | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| t1    |          1 | k_sc              |            2 | created_at  | A         |      646982 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I wonder if the problem here is the cardinality. My question is should InnoDB indexes be ordered by the higher cardinality columns closer to the the start of the index, i.e. `PRIMARY KEY (provider_id,search_id);` or does it even matter?

Comment: What index is being used to resolve the `count()`? Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to find out. Using some secondary key should be generally faster than using the primary for such query.

Comment: How big is the table?  `SHOW TABLE STATUS`  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: The columns of an index should be ordered by what is needed in `WHERE` clauses, _not_ cardinality.  [_More discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: @RickJames Do you have any benchmarks to support your theory? I don't doubt you but would like some proof to back up the claim.

Comment: @RickJames In regards to your other questions, I have about 1.3 million rows. Each row consumes 11527 bytes of data and a little less than 16GB for Maria.

Comment: I have no 'proof' that `WHERE search_id=123 AND provider_id=567` will be faster or slower depending on the order in the index.  But...  You can easily see from `EXPLAIN` or running a `SELECT` that these matter:  `search_id=123 AND provider_id > 567` versus `search_id > 123 AND provider_id=567`.  For efficiency, the "=constant" column should come before the "range" column in the `INDEX`.

Comment: @MarkD, there is no "proof" needed, if the order of columns is wrong, the where clause cannot use such index effectively (nothing after first range scan and such things, thats a fact), only if the indexes are equivalent in regards to usability in WHERE/ORDER BY/GROUP BY then ordering by cardinality might have a real positive effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @RickJames, suggested in one of the comments, cardinality has little to do with order of indexes. Therefore if your query is similar to

```
SELECT id, search_id, provider_id FROM t1 WHERE search_id=123 AND provider_id=567
```

Then the index should be ordered `search_id,provider_id`. If however you are running a more range based query.

> For efficiency, the "=constant" column should come before the "range"
>   column in the INDEX

That means whenever you have a query as follows.

```
SELECT id, search_id, provider_id FROM t1 WHERE search_id>123 AND
provider_id<567 AND columnX=1
```

Then your index should be created as follows `columnX,search_id,provider_id`.